# Ember.Button not firing

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember.Button defined in the following view and I cannot get the click event handler to bind to the controller action:

```
<label for="url_search_url">Url</label>
<input id="url_search_url" name="url_search[url]" size="30" type="search" {{bindAttr value="urlSearch.search_url"}}>
{{#view Ember.Button target="Lead.Controllers.UrlSearch" action="search" }}
        Search
{{/view}}
```

And here is my controller:

```
Lead.Controllers.UrlSearch = Ember.Object.extend
  init: ->
    @_super()

    @url_search = Lead.UrlSearch.create()

    @url_search.set('search_url', 'http://www.bdec-online.com/bd-cmpy/bd-cz.cfm')

    @view = Ember.View.create
      controller: @
      urlSearchBinding: 'controller.url_search'
      templateName: 'app/templates/url_search/show'
      didInsertElement: ->
        $('#url_search_url').focus()
      urlSearch: @

    @view.appendTo('#fieldset')

  search: ->
    console.log('got here')
```

I am pulling my hair out on this one, I simply cannot see what I am doing wrong.  I have tried setting the target attribute and the targetBinding attribute but nothing seems to work.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your problem is that your target object is a class, not an instance.

You need to create an instance of your `Lead.Controllers.UrlSearch` controller and use it as the target on your button.

Comment: I have tried setting target to an instance but it still is not firing.  I am struggling with how to debug this.  Can you suggest anything?

Comment: I also seen in travis they use targetBinding to a property of the view. Do you know of any docs showing this approach?

Comment: Updating to ember 0.9.4 from 0.9.3 solved this problem.

I thought I was going mad.  You were right initially though, I was not point to an instance.